# In C, multiple initialization of a variable is not throwing an error. Why?

Tags: c, initialization

In the below code a variable is initialized multiple times.

Why is this code not throwing an error?

```c
int main() 
{ 
  int x;
  x=5;
  x=10;
  printf("\nx=%d",x) ;
}
```

Program Output

> x = 10

Comment: That could cause an `error` if it was outside of the `main` function. but there you're just assigning a new value to the variable.

Comment: Not an actual duplicate -- possible dup is tagged both C/C++ -- the problem with that link is the answers are very C++ specific (except for the one minimal C answer). Answer below is much better for C. (which is why we should not tag questions with both C / C++ tags where potential examples can be specific to one and not the other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple initialization will throw error only if the variable is constant.
Not-constant variables can be initialized multiple times.

U can use

`const int x=0`

So that multiple initialization will not be allowed.

Answer (score 7):

You're not doing any initialization *at all*.

An initialization would be

```
int x = 0;
```

where you initialize the variable in the definition.

With e.g.

```
x = 5;
```

you only *assign* a new value to the variable `x`.

Non-constant variables are not immutable. You can assign a value to a variable as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1):

because what you only did was reassigning variable int x to another value